# How to prevent component rerendering if hook return type is not used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to prevent a component rerendering if the hook used by the component doesn't affect it's own state.

Let me explain with an example:

```
import { useState, useEffect, memo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

let renderCount = 0;

function useNothing() {
  const [nothing, setNothing] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setNothing((v) => v + 1);
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
}

function App() {
  useNothing();

  console.log(++renderCount);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Check the console</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(App);
```

As you can see from the console output, the component rerenders every 2 seconds, even if the useNothing hook doesn't affect the returned layout.

Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/exciting-hill-k6xkdr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-34%2C1)

In my real scenario I'm trying to achieve what I'm also questioning in react-hook-form Q&A here: https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/11450.

I need to watch variations on my input fields but I want to rerender the component only if one specific property of the fields change.

Comment: Thanks for using the sandbox. But this statement - `doesn't affect the returned layout.`- then why are we using it there? Can you give a more real example so we can understand.

Comment: I guess, do not call a hook you do not use ? Otherwise no. You cannot skip re-renders on components of updated hooks. You could restructure your code by breaking it up to more components, and call those components. Then the new components which do not use the hook or its value could be memoized to avoid re-renders. Or post a more relevant example so we can understand the underlying problem better.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli he can use a ref to store a value without rerendering. This can be done in a hook as well. Of course you can not do that with `useState` as rerendering on a state change is exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I think maybe this is an XY problem

Comment: This is what `useSelector` from redux do so it must be possible somehow

Comment: I guess what OP wants to do is create the hook as sort of a `background task` which he can use to run some calculations in the background, but as soon as he uses the hook inside of a component, the component render is bound to any changes caused by any hook inside of that component. So any change will ultimately cause a re-render, as per the way in which React functions.

Comment: Side note, `useSelector` will actually cause a re-render of the component if the state it listens to has changed. I.e. create a user reducer which has `username` as a property, and write `const username = useSelector(state => state.user.username)`. Every time the `username` changes, regardless of who initiates the change, will cause react to re-render the component in which that part of the state is used.

Answer (score 0):

You are actively changing the state every two seconds in your code. Of course it rerenders.

I assume you want this instead:

```
import { useState, useEffect, memo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

let renderCount = 0;

function useNothing() {
  const nothing = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
       nothing.current += 1;
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
}

function App() {
  useNothing();

  console.log(++renderCount);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Check the console</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(App);
```

Comment: Just to give a context: I'm trying to achieve what I'm also questioning in react-hook-form Q&A here: https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/11450. I need to watch variations on my input fields but I want to rerender only if one specific property of the fields change.

Comment: @c.bear If you need to update a variable without rerendering, use `useRef` and combine it with a `useState` to trigger a rerender when you need it. Setting the value of `ref.current` doesn't rerender the component but still stores the current value for the next rerender.